# Data not loading in TableView using JdbcSourceReader in [datafx]

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

With the help of the datafx samples, I wrote a simple program to populate a tableView on a simple button click in javafx. My code is as follows

```
package testjavafx;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import org.datafx.reader.DataReader;
import org.datafx.reader.JdbcSource;
import org.datafx.reader.converter.JdbcConverter;
import org.datafx.provider.ListDataProvider;


public class SampleController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> fNameCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lNameCol;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTableView;

    @FXML
    private Button loadBtn;


    ObservableList<Person> myList =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList();;

    @FXML
    void handleLoadData(ActionEvent event) {

        JdbcConverter<Person> converter = new JdbcConverter<Person>() {

            @Override
            public Person convertOneRow(ResultSet rs) {
                Person answer = new Person();
                try{
                answer.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                answer.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
                return answer;
                } catch(SQLException ex){
                    System.out.println("Sql exception in conversion\n");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        DataReader<Person> dr = new JdbcSource<>("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datafx?user=root&password=","select * from person;", converter);

//        
//        while(dr.next()){
//            System.out.println(dr.get());
//        }
        //get the list now

        ListDataProvider<Person> lodp = new ListDataProvider<>(dr);


        //System.out.println(lodp.getData().size());

        lodp.setResultObservableList(myList);
        lodp.retrieve();

       myList= lodp.getData();
//        System.out.println(myList.get(0));
        initializeTableView();
        System.out.println(myList.size());

    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert fNameCol != null : "fx:id=\"fNameCol\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Sample.fxml'.";
        assert lNameCol != null : "fx:id=\"lNameCol\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Sample.fxml'.";
        assert loadBtn != null : "fx:id=\"loadBtn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Sample.fxml'.";
    }

    private void initializeTableView() {


        personTableView =  new TableView<>(myList);
        personTableView.setEditable(true);
        fNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        fNameCol.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        lNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));
    }

}
```

On the button click, nothing happens and console only shows 'regular query'.  I checked the **DataReader** instance and it show the values from the database, but the tableview is not populated.

My person class is simple with StringProperty fields and getters and setters.

Stuck on this for long time

Comment: I also have to delete mylist = lodp.getData() as this was giving Exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new TableView, and new TableColumns. These are not the TableView and TableColumns that are defined in the FXML file and displayed in your UI.

I think you need

```
private void initializeTableView() {


    personTableView.setItems(myList);
    personTableView.setEditable(true);
    // fNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    fNameCol.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
    // lNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

James_D is right, you shouldn't create a new TableView instance but use the one provided by the @FXML Annotation.
Apart from that, you can remove the line

myList= lodp.getData();

The myList variable will already contain the retrieved data, since you passed it with lodp.setResultObservableList(myList);

Comment: Thanks Johan for commenting. I already removed the myList = lodp.getData after working with James answer.